# Is there a way to embed custom fonts in flash without flex

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fonts, flash-cs5

Just as my question says, I've never used flex and don't have the library as far as I know, but I have a custom font I want to use in my flash program, and even though I have it imported into my library, when I move my files to another computer that does not have the custom font I'm using installed, it's replaced with a system default font.

Answer (score 4):

Is this an Actionscript only project? If so, you can use the Embed metadata tag something like this:

```
[Embed(source="pathToTtfFile", fontName="FontName", mimeType="application/x-font- truetype")] 
public var myFont:Class;
```

http://inspiritgames.com/blog/2010/09/embed-fonts-into-pure-as3-project/

Otherwise, just put the text somewhere in your movie and click the Embed button and pick the characters you want embedded.

Comment: I tried this and get a message that says "You have used a feature that requires the Flex SDK "Embed" metadata"  And tries to make me add Flex to my project.

Comment: Create a Class mx.core.FontAsset that extends Font and implements IFlexAsset, and the message should go away.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Flex in this project, but I ended up creating the fonts in my library instead.  Thanks :)

Comment: The solution I posted doesn't require flex, but if you're happy, I'm happy.